# validación dinámica lessThan / greaterThan

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, validación

Tengo dos campos. El primero (A) tiene un mínimo que se calcula sobre la cantidad del segundo (B). Cuando el B cambia, el `min` de A cambia.

¿Cúal es el problema? La primera vez que se establece el mínimo de A (por ejemplo 30), la validación se realiza correctamente. Pero ahora, cuando cambio el valor de B y se restablece el mínimo de A (15)... sigue validando con los valores anteriores (30).

He intentado pegar todo el código en el snippet, pero no funciona la validación. No se si serán las librerías o al inicializarlo. Que yo tengo repartido el código entre masterpages etc... y me ha costado copiarlo todo. De todas formas para haceros una idea de lo que hay.

```js
$("#Hueco_Pagina_gvPresupuestos_txtImportes_3").change(function(e){
    $(this).attr({
        "min":ValidarOtrosCostes(),
        "data-bv-greaterthan-value":ValidarOtrosCostes()
    });
    console.log(ValidarOtrosCostes());
    $('form').bootstrapValidator('updateStatus', $("#Hueco_Pagina_gvPresupuestos_txtImportes_3"), 'NOT_VALIDATED').bootstrapValidator('validateField', $("#Hueco_Pagina_gvPresupuestos_txtImportes_3"));
});    
        
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $('form').bootstrapValidator({
            excluded: [':disabled']});
    $("#Hueco_Pagina_gvPresupuestos_txtImportes_3")
        .attr({
            "min":ValidarOtrosCostes(),
            "data-bv-greaterthan-value":ValidarOtrosCostes()
        });
    console.log(ValidarOtrosCostes());
    $('form').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', $("#Hueco_Pagina_gvPresupuestos_txtImportes_3"));
});
        
function ValidarOtrosCostes(){
  var gastopersonal = CastFloat( $("#Hueco_Pagina_gvPresupuestos_txtImportes_2").val() );
  var otroscostes = CastFloat( $("#Hueco_Pagina_gvPresupuestos_txtImportes_3").val() );
  var porcentaje = ((gastopersonal * 15) / 100);
  return porcentaje;
}

function CastFloat(Cantidad) {
  Cantidad = replaceAll(Cantidad, ".", "");
  Cantidad = replaceAll(Cantidad, ",", ".");
  return parseFloat(Cantidad);
}

function replaceAll(text, busca, reemplaza) {
  while (text.toString().indexOf(busca) != -1)
    text = text.toString().replace(busca, reemplaza);
  return text;
}

function QuitarMillares(e) {
  var obj = e.currentTarget;
  var valor = CastFloat(obj.value);
  if (!isNaN(valor)) {
      obj.value = valor.toFixed(2).replace(".", ",");
  }
  else {
      obj.value = "0,00"
  }
}

function soloNumDeciPositivos(e) {
  var tecla = (e.which) ? e.which : event.keyCode;
  return ((tecla >= 48 && tecla <= 57) || (tecla == 44) || (tecla == 43) || (tecla == 13));
}

function ponerDecimales(e) {
  //e.currentTarget.value = parseFloat(e.currentTarget.value.replace(",", ".")).toFixed(2).replace(".", ",");
  var obj = e.currentTarget;
  var valor = CastFloat(obj.value);
  //var aux = obj.value.search(","); //Saca la Posicion del Decimal
  if (!isNaN(valor))
  {
      obj.value = valor.toFixed(2).replace(".", ",");
      obj.value = obj.value.toString().split('').reverse().join('').replace(/(?=\d*\.?)(\d{3})/g, '$1.').split('').reverse().join('').replace(/^[\.]/, '');
  }
  else
  { 
      obj.value = "0,00"
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.2/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.2/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input name="ctl00$Hueco_Pagina$gvPresupuestos$ctl04$txtImportes" type="text" value="80,00" maxlength="24" id="Hueco_Pagina_gvPresupuestos_txtImportes_2" class="form-control importe" onkeypress="return soloNumDeciPositivos(event);" onblur="return ponerDecimales(event);" onfocus="return QuitarMillares(event);" max="999999999999999,99" data-bv-lessthan-message="El importe es demasiado grande" style="text-align: right;" data-bv-field="ctl00$Hueco_Pagina$gvPresupuestos$ctl04$txtImportes">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input name="ctl00$Hueco_Pagina$gvPresupuestos$ctl05$txtImportes" type="text" value="50,00" maxlength="24" id="Hueco_Pagina_gvPresupuestos_txtImportes_3" class="form-control importe" onkeypress="return soloNumDeciPositivos(event);" onblur="return ponerDecimales(event);" onfocus="return QuitarMillares(event);" max="999999999999999,99" data-bv-lessthan-message="El importe es demasiado grande" style="text-align: right;" min="13.5" data-bv-greaterthan-value="13.5" data-bv-field="ctl00$Hueco_Pagina$gvPresupuestos$ctl05$txtImportes">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: ¿Lo que quieres es que se reajusten los valores mínimos y máximos según lo que el usuario vaya introduciendo en los campos para poder pasar el validador de bootstrap?

Comment: @JaviMollá lo que pasa es que los valores si que se reajustan (en el html) pero parece ser que el validador no los "refresca". Cuando llamas al revalidate por ejemplo sigue leyendo el min antiguo en lugar del que hay en el html tras el cambio. No se si es posible que se mantenga el atributo...

Comment: @JaviMollá de todas formas ya lo he solucionado con otro atributo de BootstrapValidator, El "callback"